# Facebook canvas url with or without www

Tags: facebook, https, facebook-canvas

I've made a website, which relies on Facebook OAuth in order for the user to participate in a competition.

The canvas URL within Facebook differentiates between https://www.mycompetition.com/ and https://mycompetition.com

Our server is set up to receive both entries, but if I enter the site using www, Facebook complains that the URL doesn't match when authorizing.

Do you know how to make Facebook accept both entries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, by the way. The webserver now contains two websites. The first contains the website, the second one just redirects to the first one, using JS. Easy :)